# Range of Even Function

Tags: functions

Is it possible for an even function to have the entire set of real numbers as the range? I thought much about it but I didn't find. Please explain if anybody knows.

Answer (score 6):

Take $f(x)=x\sin x$ as what you want!

Comment: Thank you so much for your fruitful help.

Answer (score 2):

How about $x^{2m} \cos(nx)$  a bit of generalization I think.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What are the values of m? I think the values of n are integers.

Comment: m is natural no. and yes n can be any integer.